# Cassandra Query Language: get maximal key

Tags: cassandra, hector, cql

I need to get a maximal key of a column family an cassandra database for further use. How can I get it using cassandra query language or hector API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using an ordered partitioner, which is usually a bad idea, getting the maximal key in a column family is very expensive.  See [this](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/cluster_architecture/partitioning) article for more details about random versus ordered partitioner.

Generally you want to structure your cassandra data model so that you do gets on a single key, rather than gets on a range of keys.  Often you have to denormalize your data to do so.

Comment: I absolutely agree. You can scan all keys and get maximal value within your app. this is very expensive. I suggest t0 maintain list of keys in different structure (Column Family) if you need to look it up quickly.